# How to use Light UIUserInterfaceStyle image version in Dark Mode?

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, ios-darkmode, uiuserinterfacestyle

I use image, this image has two versions for light and dark `UIUserInterfaceStyle`, but I need to use the image light version in one `UIViewController` when Dark Mode is on. I know I can use `tintColor`, but I want to find out if other ways to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Subramanian's answer is perfect for this use case.

However, I you really need just the `UIImage` in a different style, you can do the following:

```
// create a trait collection with `light` interface style
let traitCollection = UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .light)

// If you have an existing image, you can change it's style like this: 
let lightImage = image.withConfiguration(traitCollection.imageConfiguration)

// Or if you load the image by name, you can do this:
let lightImage = UIImage(named: "imageName", in: nil, compatibleWith: traitCollection)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can opt out of dark mode for a particular view controller by setting the overrideUserInterfaceStyle property in viewDidLoad function. Sample snippet as follows.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Always adopt a light interface style.    
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
    }
```

To opt out dark mode for your image view you can set as follows.

```
imageview. overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
```

You can check out further about opt out of dark mode from the link below. Hope it helps.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface/choosing_a_specific_interface_style_for_your_ios_app

Comment: No, I'm sorry I mean light version of the image, not UIViewController

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can also set overrideUserInterfaceStyle of imageview to opt out of dark mode for the particular imageview.